# How to secure USB connections mechanically

Tags: usb, usb-device, mechanical-assembly

What is the recommended way to secure USB Type A connections to their ports to protect against vibration (such as from a human walking, or if it was in a vehicle), in manner that will last at least around a year, assuming that screw locking USB ports are not available? I've read suggestions of

1. Hot Melt
2. Neutral cure silicone
3. Epoxy resin

but I'm not sure which is the most suitable. Should hot melt even be considered? I also am not keen on potting the enclosure.

Comment: Sounds more like a superuser or serverfault question. We have no idea about your production environment BTW.

Comment: As it stands your question is lacking enough information to get a helpful answer, or to be helpful to others.  Please read the site guidelines on asking good questions, and then update your question to be both more specific and also to give enough information that it can be answered properly.

Comment: are you designing these systems? USB-C has locking connectors with a screw, specified in the standard. For anything else, you'd probably want to use an industrial-speced connector that guarantees some mechanical reliability – and also re-connectability, should you want that.

Comment: Apologies for the vague question, I've added more specific information in.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've seen screwed locking connectors for USB-A and USB-B too, though I'm not sure if they're part of the standard or a nonstandard extension.

Answer (score 1):

I'd honestly avoid anything that might be getting into the connector.

Also, USB connectors are often shrouded with very low-energy plastics or worse, soft silicone, so that glueing them is pretty hard.

The usual way is to screw your device to a solid baseplate or similar, add a support below your external connector that holds it at the right vertical position without putting mechanical stress on it, and then solidly affix the connector to that (cable ties, hose clamp, screws holding the top of the connector in place). Make sure everything is rigid enough so that the actual connection doesn't become the place where mechanical vibration differences occur.